# OpenLayers: draw a shape (square or circle) where the user clicks on map

Tags: openlayers, map-drawing, draw-interaction

In OpenLayers 6, using OSM, I'm trying to draw either a square or a circle where the user clicks on a map. The shape should be (around) 5km of side or radius.

So far I've produced the following to draw a square:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    var feat = new Feature(new Point(e.coordinate));
    feat.setStyle(new Style({
        image: new RegularShape({
            stroke: new Stroke({color: '#333', width: 2}),
            points: 4,
            radius: 40,
            angle: Math.PI / 4,
        }),
    }));
    const source = new VectorSource({features: [feat]});
    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({source: source});
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
});
```

Unfortunately the box seems agnostic of what map is being displayed, and when I zoom in/out the shape remains with its same actual dimension. Is there a way to **draw a rectangle with given 4 coordinates**, or **a circle with coordinates of its center and a radius** ?

I have noticed the [draw-shape example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html) in OpenLayers website, but presented solution isn't what I'm looking for: I'm not searching in fact for a double click interaction from the user (one click for the center, one for the radius/size of the shape), but rather I only want one-click interaction.

Comment: You need a polygon, not a point.  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html

Comment: If I've correctly understood the API, I'm changing the Feature constructor call with `new Feature(new Polygon([[x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3], [x4,y4], [x1,y1]]));`; but nothing is displayed on the map. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: nor this `var feat = new Feature(circular(e.coordinate, 5000));` works

Comment: `new Feature({geometry: fromCircle(new Circle(e.coordinate, 5000))})` this is working, thanks